# Object oriented code reuse in iOS and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, ios6

I have a viewController in my iOS class and in viewDidLoad, I create a gradient with CAGradient and add it to the layer of my view.  I want this to appear in other views too, so what's the best way to do that? (New to objective-c and ios, I know how to do this in PHP and C#).

Comment: how much difference between C# way?

Comment: i'm getting used to the syntax and the properties, protocols and delegation

Comment: OO concept remain the same, if you have problem about syntax, learn them first

Comment: so I create a CAGradient class and call it as a property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to make a category on CALayer, and add a method to create and add your custom gradient. Something like this:

```
@implementation CALayer (CustomGradient)

-(void)addCustomGradient {
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(.25, 0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithHue:.5 saturation:.6 brightness:1 alpha:1].CGColor,(id)[UIColor colorWithHue:.65 saturation:.6 brightness:1 alpha:.5].CGColor];
gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.0f,@1.00f];
[self insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "CALayer+CustomGradient.h"


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view.layer addCustomGradient];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to make a base class that all your other view controllers that you want the gradient on inherit from. Just do what you are doing in viewDidLoad in the base class.

One thing to remember, if you override viewDidLoad in any of the subclasses, don't forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]` so that the gradient code still gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Objective-C specific way to solve this. You should be able to pull across solutions from other languages. My personal recommendation would be to pull the `CAGradientLayer` out into a `UIView` subclass, that way you don't have to mix layer and view hierarchies (you also get the touch handling benefits of `UIView`). A good implementation of this is [`OBGradientView`](https://github.com/ole/OBGradientView). This should also simplify the code enough that there really isn't any duplication.

From here, it depends on how where the view is reused. If you have several different view controllers that all use the same gradient in the same position, then you can make a `UIViewController` subclass like @Lance recommends. This should be a fairly rare use case though.

If you're using the same gradient in myriad places across your app, I would typically add a class method to a `Theme` object – just a simple subclass of `NSObject` – that makes that specific gradient, which I adapted from [WWDC 2012 session 216](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216). There's no practical difference from adding these methods as a category; I just find that splits up code too much.

I would strongly recommend against rdelmar's solution because it is a) stateful and b) not flexible. That method doesn't give you a pointer to the `CAGradientLayer`, so you can't make a modification to it. Even if it did, you can imagine a case where you *don't* want to add a layer to the hierarchy – perhaps you want to replace the layer of another object instead, or wait until after the user takes an action to add the layer to the hierarchy.